# Replacing submit buttons with icon- basics

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been using the Underscores (_s) (a blank wordpress template). It's great- but I'm losing confidence because I can't grasp how to change something so simple.

I want to replace the submit button with an icon (a Font-Awesome icon) at various places (such as the mobile menu button, and the search function).

I can get the icons to appear- but I can't establish how to make them functional (ie they are not clickable).

I can't seem to find a simple source explaining on how this is done.

Could anyone advise on the basic principles behind replacing a "submit" (or any other) button?

Thanks

My site is [here](http://www.yarnball.net.au) for an example.

Answer (score 6):

**html**

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-youricon"></i></button>
```

**CSS**

```
button{
     border:0;
     background:none;
     /*And other css to remove the default button property */    
}
```